# Find Furthest Number from 0 within Dynamic Ranges VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel workbook where there is a maximum of 6 data sets but the length or amount of data within the data set is variable/dynamic. I want to be able to find the furthest value from 0 within all of the A-Axis_Disp Columns (see image below). I think I am on the right track with my code but don't know how to finish it off. Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated. TIA. [image]

Here is my code:

```
Sub FindFurthestNoFromZero()
    Dim iRng As Range
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Dim Rng3 As Range
    Dim NewRng1 As Range
    Dim val As Variant
    Dim B As Integer
    Dim Dispws As Worksheet

    Set Dispws = Sheets("Disp_&_Result_Calc")

    Set iRng = Dispws.Range(Dispws.Cells(1, 1), Dispws.Cells(1, Dispws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).column))

    B = 0
    Do Until B = Sheets("Hidden").Range("G2").Value + 1

        For Each cel In iRng
            If cel.Value = "A-Axis_Disp" Then
                Set Rng1 = cel.EntireColumn.Find(What:="", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
                Debug.Print Rng1.FormulaR1C1
                Set Rng2 = Dispws.Cells(Rng1.row - 1, Rng1.column)
                Debug.Print Rng2.FormulaR1C1
                Set Rng3 = Cells(cel.row + 1, cel.column)
                Debug.Print Rng3.FormulaR1C1

                Set NewRng1 = Range(Rng3.Address & ":" & Rng2.Address)
                Debug.Print NewRng1.Address

                For Each cell In Range("NewRng1")
                    val = cell.Value
                Next cell
            End If
        Next cel
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Fixed indentation. I've also added a missing `End If`, assuming its position - feel free to fix if that's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Would a formula suffice?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C, IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(AGGREGATE(14,6,ABS(0-C2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(E1+99,C:C))),1),AGGREGATE(14,6,ABS(0-H2:INDEX(H:H,MATCH(E1+99,H:H))),1)), C:C, 0),
                            MATCH(0-MAX(AGGREGATE(14,6,ABS(0-C2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(E1+99,C:C))),1),AGGREGATE(14,6,ABS(0-H2:INDEX(H:H,MATCH(E1+99,H:H))),1)), C:C,0))),
        INDEX(H:H, IFERROR(MATCH(MAX(AGGREGATE(14,6,ABS(0-C2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(E1+99,C:C))),1),AGGREGATE(14,6,ABS(0-H2:INDEX(H:H,MATCH(E1+99,H:H))),1)), H:H, 0),
                           MATCH(0-MAX(AGGREGATE(14,6,ABS(0-C2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(E1+99,C:C))),1),AGGREGATE(14,6,ABS(0-H2:INDEX(H:H,MATCH(E1+99,H:H))),1)), H:H,0))))
```

[image]

Comment: I'd edit to say "would a *simple* formula suffice", but... ;-)

Comment: I want my worksheet to be clean and I also have a dynamic range so I thought I would have to use vba? correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if this is what you are after

without code:

```
cell AF1:  =MIN(C:C,H:H,M:M,R:R,W:W,AB:AB)
cell AF2:  =MAX(C:C,H:H,M:M,R:R,W:W,AB:AB)
cell AF3:  =IF(ABS(AF1)>AF2,AF1,AF2)              this is your answer
```

VBA code:

```
Sub minMax()

    Dim min As Long
    Dim max As Long

    min = Application.WorksheetFunction.min(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C,H:H,M:M,R:R,W:W,AB:AB"))
    max = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C,H:H,M:M,R:R,W:W,AB:AB"))

    If Abs(min) > max Then
        Debug.Print "extreme at "; min
    ElseIf Abs(min) < max Then
        Debug.Print "extreme at "; max
    Else
        Debug.Print "extremes at "; min; " and "; max
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Clever answer. The formula works fairly well, the only issue being the hard coded ranges (set up your formula, and then add a column before "B"). The formula can be set to properly update for this, but your code cannot. Also worth noting, it only shows the max/min value (which is what the OP asked for), but if his next step is somehow using the cell...well that will require something completely new.

Answer (score 0):

here is a rewrite of my first posting

it looks for all A-Axis_Disp columns up to column ZZ (this can be changed)

i left the debugging lines in the code (currently commented out ... delete them if you like)

```
Sub minMax()

    Dim aaa As Range

    Dim min As Long
    Dim max As Long

    Dim colm As Long
    Dim colOffset As Long

    Dim searchRange As String        ' this is plugged into application.evaluate argument

    colm = Application.Evaluate("=IFNA(MATCH(""A-Axis_Disp"",1:1,0),0)")       ' find first column
    If colm > 0 Then
        Set aAxisData = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(colm)
'       aAxisData.Select                                                       ' for debugging only
    Else
        Exit Sub       ' exit if no column found. something more can be put here
    End If

'   Debug.Print Split(Sheets("sheet1").Range("zz4").Address(1, 0), "$")(0)         ' debug only
'   Debug.Print Split(Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, colm + 1).Address(1, 0), "$")(0)   ' debug only

    Do While True

        searchRange = Split(Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, colm + 1).Address(1, 0), "$")(0) & "1:ZZ1"
'       Debug.Print searchRange                                          ' for debugging only

        colOffset = Application.Evaluate("=IFNA(MATCH(""A-Axis_Disp""," & searchRange & ",0),0)")
         If colOffset = 0 Then Exit Do

        colm = colm + colOffset
'       Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(colm).Select                            ' for debugging only
        Set aAxisData = Union(aAxisData, Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(colm))
    Loop
'   aAxisData.Select                                                     ' for debugging only

    min = Application.WorksheetFunction.min(aAxisData)
    max = Application.WorksheetFunction.max(aAxisData)


    If Abs(min) > max Then
        Debug.Print "extreme is "; min
    ElseIf Abs(min) < max Then
        Debug.Print "extreme is "; max
    Else
        Debug.Print "extremes are "; min; " and "; max
    End If
End Sub
```